# How to find hrefs that contain multiple strings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking to find any anchor tags that have an href that contain `example.com` and **DONT CONTAIN** `vendor_id`. Something like this...

```
$('a[href*="example.com" && href!*="vendor_id"]')
```

here's an example of the anchor i would find... `<a href="http://www.example.com/?vendor_id=1>`

Is this possible? Thanks for your help!

Edit: I don't think there is a selector for 'does not contain' but does this work? `$('a[href*="example.com"]:not([href*="vendor_id")')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector and wrap the second attribute selector in a `:not()`

```
$('a[href*="example.com"]:not([href*="vendor_id"])')
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/X9qna/

Answer (score 1):

You can stack attribute selectors like this to achieve what you need:

```
a[href*="example.com"][href!*="vendor_id"]
```

Comment: No idea. Just answered based on the selectors he used.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('a[href*="example.com"]').filter('a[href*="vendor_id"]').remove();
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Smpm4/